# Werden Regeln gebogen oder gebeugt?

Tags: word-choice, phrase, idiomaticity

Kürzlich schrieb hier jemand: „[…] Stefan Zweig is bending the rules to his purposes […]“ Als ich daraufhin die Frage gestellt hatte, welche **Regeln** Zweig denn **gebogen** haben soll, hat man mich verbessert: Er habe die **Regeln gebeugt**.

Nun kenne ich den Ausdruck

> sich die **Regeln** zurecht**biegen**

Daher sagt mir mein Sprachempfinden: selbst wenn nicht zurecht, man **biegt Regeln**, und daher sollte es **biegen**, **bog**, **gebogen** sein. Mir ist auch geläufig, dass man

> das **Recht beugen**

kann, im übertragenen Sinne also die Göttin Justitia. Hier ist es also **beugen**, **beugte**, **gebeugt**.

Doch wieso sollte man Regeln zurecht**biegen** dürfen, nicht aber nur **biegen** sondern ***beugen***?

Comment: Zu *Regeln gebogen* finde ich nur dieses Beispiel und ein Zitat desselben: (https://diepresse.com/home/panorama/oesterreich/5392404/Staedtebau_Neue-WelterbeWaechterin-kritisiert-Wien_Regeln-wurden). Zu *Regeln beugte* drei: (https://www.google.at/search?q=die+Regeln+beugte&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en-gb&client=safari)

Comment: Zu *Regeln biegen* dieses: (https://www.1815.ch/news/wallis/aktuell/klischee-verbiegen-die-regeln/) und dieses: (https://www.jura.uni-bonn.de/fileadmin/Fachbereich_Rechtswissenschaft/Einrichtungen/Institute/Voelkerrecht/Dokumente_fuer_Webseite/Die_Zeit_6.11.2014_S_8-9.pdf), wobei das zweite eine Anspielung auf *biegen und brechen* ist.

Comment: Normalerweise _dehnt_ man Regeln.

Comment: @Crissov oder gibt es vielleicht doch einen semantischen Unterschied? *Beugen* für das übertreten, ähnlich dem brechen und *dehnen* für die sehr freie Auslegung?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wie @tofro schon kommentiert hat, bedeutet *biegen* eine dauerhafte Veränderung (physikalisch wird der Fließpunkt des Materials überschritten, so dass es nicht mehr zurückfedert), während *beugen* etwas Temporäres ist.

Von daher würde *sich die Regeln zurechtbiegen* bedeuten, dass man die Regel **verändert** (zumindest in der eigenen frechen Interpretation), sodass sie einem angenehmer ist. Da schwingt auch die Implikation mit, dass es sich um einen länger andauernden Regelverstoß handelt (wenn ein Autokonzern jahrelang Abgasmessungen betrügt, als rein hypothetisches Beispiel).

Stefan Zweig hat die Regeln hingegen *gebeugt*, das heißt soweit belastet (durch großzügige Auslegung), dass sie ihm gepasst haben, aber nicht soweit, dass ihm jemand daraus einen Strick hätte drehen können.

Unabhängig von der genauen Bedeutung gibt es aber im Deutschen eben nur die beiden Redewendungen "die Regeln beugen" und "sich die Regeln zurechtbiegen".

Comment: Das ist interessant, denn mit dem englischen _to bend_ allein kann dieser wichtige Unterschied gar nicht ausgedrückt werden. Bei "... Stefan Zweig is bending the rules to his purposes ..." erschließt sich also erst durch den Kontext, ob _bending_ mit _biegt_ oder mit _beugt_ zu übersetzen ist.

Comment: Richtig, aber die Redewendung "die Regeln biegen" gibts im Deutschen halt nicht.

Comment: Zurechtbiegen schon.

Answer (score 0):

Biegen und Beugen sind sehr ähnliche Wörter, sie beschreiben ähnliche oder gar gleiche geometrische Verformungen unterschiedlicher materieller Objekte. Von daher ist es nicht verwunderlich, daß für ein immaterielles Wort wie "Regel" umgangssprachlich mal das eine, mal das andere verwendet wird, und Justita wird dich für die vermeintliche falsche Verwendung des einen nicht strafen können.

Man kann eine Regel (oder auch das Recht) eigentlich nicht beugen, biegen oder dehnen, entweder man bricht sie oder nicht. Daß eine Regel gebeugt wird liegt in der Regel daran, daß sie nicht gut bzw. eindeutig formuliert ist.

Comment: Ählich, aber nicht gleich: *Biegen* ist (zumindestens bei nichtelastischen Dingen wie Eisenstangen und - hoffentlich auch - Regeln) ein irreversibler Prozeß und würde damit die Regeln *dauerhaft verändern*, während *beugen* normalerweise (außer bei Hexenschuß) zum Ausgangspunkt zurückkehrt.

Comment: @tofro Da geht mir doch glatt ein Licht auf, denn bislang war ich mir des Unterschieds gar nicht so bewusst.

Comment: @tofro Sehe ich nicht so, du kannst alles wieder gerade biegen, was auch umgangssprachlich so verwendet wird. Und eine Regel wird nie zurechtgebogen, so daß sie eine neue Bedeutung bekommt. Es wird eine bestehende Regel unterschiedlich weit ausgelegt oder anders interpretiert, sie wird aber im Kern nicht verändert und bleibt im Originalen bestehen. Von daher würde nach deiner Lesart beugen besser passen, aber ich stimme dem nicht zu.

Comment: Ich denke, der Unterschied, den ich oben beschrieben habe, ist auch der Grund dafür, dass man das Recht *beugen*, aber nicht *biegen* kann.